# C++ pointer function implementation for a class within class

Tags: c++, class, header, c++14

My header file "DoublyLinkedLists" looks like this

```
class DoublyLinkedLists{
private:
    struct element{
        int key;
        struct element *prev, *next;
    };
    element* head = NULL;
    element* tail = NULL;
public:
    void insertToHead(int insert);
    element *find(int insert);
 
};
```

In the cpp file that includes "DoublyLinkedLists" header, I implemented my function(insert to head) like this:

```
void DoublyLinkedLists::insertToHead(int insert){
  //some code
}
```

I've tried, but doesnt work

```
DoublyLinkedLists::element* find(int insert){
//code
}
```

But how can I implement a function "element *find(int insert)" in a cpp file that returns a pointer? Where must I write "DoublyLinkedLists::" that specifies from where I am taking a function, or must I write something else.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I'm new to object oriented C++ programming and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: C++ OOP is pretty much the same as C++ not-OOP except that you have an invisible parameter called `this`. Would you know how to write it if it was `element *find(DoublyLinkedLists *this, int insert);` and it wasn't in a class?

Comment: In case that is the point of confusion: The `*` in front of `find` is part of the return type. It means the same as `element* find(int insert);`.

Comment: @bruh So is your question really why `element* DoublyLinkedLists::find(int insert) { /* some code */ }` doesn't work?

Comment: to make what @user17732522 said even clearer: the spaces don't mean anything. `element*find`, `element *find`, `element* find` and `element   *        find` all mean the same thing (and the `*` is part of `element*` and not part of `*find`)

Comment: It is exceptionally hard to show you where you are going wrong, how to fix it, and how to avoid similar problems in the future if you do not show us what you are doing. I strongly recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask] as they contain the minimum information needed to have a good Stack Overflow experience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample implementation what you are supposed to do. I don't know if tail->next == head so I check tail seperately.

```
DoublyLinkedLists::element* DoublyLinkedLists::find(int insert)
{
    element* current = head; // Our current node we are checking.
    while(current != tail) // as long as we aren't at the end do
    {
        if (current->key == insert) // check if the current is the one we are looking for
            return current; // return it 
        current = current->next; // else go to the next element and repeat
    }
    if (tail->key == insert) // at least we check the tail
        return tail;
   return NULL; // if "insert" is not in our list we return NULL
}
```

You wrote `element *find(int insert)` I want to point out that the `*` is linked to `element` you return a pointer of element. It is more clear if you change the function signature to `element* find(int insert)`

Edit:
Some pointer explanation. What is a pointer?
Every pointer is either 4-bytes long (32 bit) or 8-bytes long. A pointer holds a memory address. The type of pointer (int*, double*, element*, ...) tells the compiler 1) how many bytes to read on the given address and 2) how to interpret them.

Example:

```
int i = 100; // Let's say i is on adress 0x00000004
int* pI = &i; // pI = 0x00000004 (!) pI is exacly only the address not the value

std::cout << pI; // output: "0x00000004"
std::cout << *pI; // output: 100;
```

`*pI` simply tells the compiler "go to adress 0x00000004, take `sizeof(int)`(4) bytes and trat them as integer."
So the compiler takes bytes 0x00000004 to 0x00000008.

Comment: That won't compile and probably for the reason OP is confused. I don't think they were asking for the implementation of the function.

Comment: @user17732522 Added DoublyLinkedLists::element*. Thanks for the advice now it should compile without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

My question was poorly written, but all I've been looking was for a syntax of the function find.

```
DoublyLinkedLists::element *DoublyLinkedLists::find(int insert){
 //here is original code, but its quite long
  return nullptr;
}
```